# Overcoming softlock when creating /system/xbin on Android 9

Tags: 9.0-pie, magisk, busybox

Hoo roo,

Installing [Linux Deploy](https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy) (Linux chroot with root) on Android 9 requires that you install a [custom version of busybox](https://github.com/meefik/busybox). However, due to system-as-root limitations on Android 9, you can encounter problems when attempting to run the custom busybox installer. The community has found a [solution to overcome this](https://github.com/meefik/busybox/issues/93), but I can't seem to get it to work.

My tablet is a rooted Onyx Boox Max 3 that has TWRP installed without a custom ROM, with dm-verity disabled.

Running `` ls -l `which su` ``  from a terminal emulator returns  `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 1970-02-11 19:10 /sbin/su -> ./magisk` so confirms that I am using the root busybox.

`mkdir /system/xbin`after mounting /system as per instructions softlocks the tablet. Have also tried running `mount -o rw,remount /sbin/magisk/mirror/system_root` which also softlocks.

Are there any other options that I can try? Would really love a chroot of Arch on my eink tablet instead of just a proot. Would make for a much smoother experience.

Cannot emphasise how desperate I am, my failsafe is a proot using nix-on-droid, but reckon that performance will suffer. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

actually all you need is place 3 files, no need to install anything

`/data/adb/modules/busybox-ndk/module.prop`

```
id=busybox-ndk
name=Busybox for Android NDK
version=1.31.1
versionCode=13115
author=osm0sis @ xda-developers
description=Static busybox binary for all Android architectures built with the NDK
support=https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2239421
```

`/data/adb/modules/busybox-ndk/service.sh`

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/xbin/busybox --install -s /system/xbin
```

`/data/adb/modules/busybox-ndk/system/xbin/busybox`

Comment: Am a little confused on what to do here. Have confirmed that the module.prop file exists already (installed from the magisk installer), and have created the service.sh file.
Attempting to run the service.sh file returns the following error `/system/xbin/busybox: not found` 
Am not sure about the significance of the last directory either. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Hoo roo again, have recorded a voice message to properly convey what I've attempted. Cheers mate :) https://voca.ro/179SxVR5uKP4

Comment: you can download modules straight from magisk manager, no need to place files manually. this is just bare minimum example what's inside module and how to bind mount overlay files in /system/xbin without modifying /system. you probably lacking the third file which is the desired binary itself